# What design software to use to create a styleguide?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm a junior UX developer, tasked to create a styleguide for a project. What software do you use to create a styleguide? Sketch, Illustrator, or Photoshop?

**edit**
The styleguide is actually a design system. So this design system will include:

- brand (color palette, typography)
- pattern library (grids, components, etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by styleguide, can you please include an example?

Comment: That depends, is it digital or print?

Comment: Whatever works.. it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Whatever program you're most comfortable using, I would suggest a page layout program. I designed my companies in InDesign.

Comment: It can be as basic as a list of notes. That suggests Notepad (the software or the paper based equivalent).

Comment: Great questions! @שelz I updated the question with more info.

Comment: @zeethreepio digital

Comment: Microsoft Word or Google Docs are perfect for this.

Comment: I agree with the comments to use what you're most comfortable with. Personally, I'd use Sketch or Illustrator and mock up prototypes with InVision (if necessary). If it was for print I would go with InDesign, but again, that's what I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Even with the edit.. it really doesn't matter. Use whatever works for you and provides the final format (PDF? JPG? HTML?) you want.